# Test if python class is str, list, etc

Tags: python, boolean, conditional-statements, python-class

I have a list of classes:

```
[<class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'datetime.date'>, <class 'decimal.Decimal'>, <class 'decimal.Decimal'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'datetime.date'>, <class 'decimal.Decimal'>, <class 'decimal.Decimal'>, <class 'decimal.Decimal'>]
```

I want to do a boolean test similar to isinstance():

```
[isinstance(x, str) for x in l]
```

but isinstance() only takes objects not classes.

The results I want, for the above list to test if a class was a string, would be something like:

```
[True, True, True, True, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False]
```

Comment: Use `issubclass` instead of `isinstance`.

Comment: Classes *are* objects. The issue is that the *class* `str` is not an instance of `str`; it's an instance of `type`. It's subclass of itself, but (if you aren't worried about subclassing) you can do direct class comparison with `is`: `[x is str for x in l]`.

Comment: Thanks @chepner! issubclass worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `==` operator:

```
[x == str for x in l]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a list of classes, you'll want to use [`issubclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#issubclass) rather than [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```py
[issubclass(x, str) for x in l]
```

From the Python docs:

> `issubclass(class, classinfo)`
>
> Return `True` if class is a subclass (direct, indirect, or virtual) of `classinfo`. A class is considered a subclass of itself. `classinfo` may be a tuple of class objects or a [Union Type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-union), in which case return `True` if class is a subclass of any entry in `classinfo`. In any other case, a `TypeError` exception is raised.